# Finding the image of a set under the mapping $w = \sqrt{\cos z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Find the image of $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}:0 < \Re(z) < \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \Im(z)>0 \}$ under the mapping $w = \sqrt{\cos z}$.

**My attmept:** I first started by finding the image of the set under the mapping of $\cos z$ rather than $\sqrt{\cos z}$  -- which became $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}:\Re(z) > 0, \Im(z) < 0 \}$. From here, we can now map this new set with the squareroot function, which will result in $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: -\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\arg(z)<0 \}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks corrrect.